# How to add ICU library to Qt project for ARM?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, arm, icu

I've been trying to compile a Qt project with both the **ICU** (**International Components for Unicode**) libraries for x86 and ARM, but it gives the following error:

```
"libicudata.so: file not recognized: file format not recognized"
```

Make is configured with `CXX="arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-g++ -march=armv5e -marm -mthumb-interwork"`

Any solutions to how to solve this problem? Any help and/or opinion is greatly appreciated!

Side-note: if there is more information to be provided, please tell me what to specify!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

It was a linking problem, I had to add libicuuc and libicudata.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you are trying to use your x86 version of ICU to build your ARM version of Qt.

You first need to get ICU for ARM.